# Wordpress $wpdb->get_results returning local timezone, not UTC

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, timestamp

Timestamp is saved in database as 2016-05-04 14:54:18 -- UTC

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name;
$devices = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

$devices returns a timestamp of 2016-05-04 09:54:18(which is the local timestamp) -- not sure why this is happening.

- Using MAMP
- Using PHP 5.6.10

Comment: Would it be a solution to change your [timezone to UTC](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/timezone-utc-gmt-settings-in-wordpress) ? Otherwise wordpress will always try to use your local timezone. If you don't want to change your parameter, you may always change the received time to UTC using native php date functions.

Comment: The timezone in the DB is UTC. The php functions are in UTC. Why it's converting the UTC to local -- is where my confusion is

Answer (score 1):

If you have the SQL value `INSERTed` as `UTC_TIMESTAMP` (rather than just `TIMESTAMP`). When you do your `SELECT` query use `CONVERT_TZ(dt, from, to)` where `dt` could be whatever that column name is, `from` could be 'UTC' and `to` could be 'Mumbai, India' (or whatever timezone you want to convert to).

`SELECT CONVERT_TZ(date_entered, 'UTC', 'Dublin, Ireland') FROM tablename`

Comment: It is a UTC timestamp in my database. Shouldn't it give me a UTC value back. It seems to be converting automatically.